# Windows Account to read all users directories?

Tags: c#

Is it possible to create a Windows 10 account that can be used in a C# program to read all users directories (if they are not encrypted)?  I'm looking to create an account that I can use to look for duplicate images across user profiles.  The following code gives me an access denied on the the Documents and Settings folder even when I run the code in an elevated manner.

```
DirectoryInfo diInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users");
var dirs = diInfo.EnumerateDirectories("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

I get an UnauthorizedAccessException with this code even though I can access all of the folders within the Users directory through Windows Explorer.  In the application manifest file I have the requestedExecutionLevel set as follows:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel  level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="false" />
```

I noticed in Explorer I have to click on Permanently get access to this colder.  Is there a way to do this in C#?

Comment: Just curious.... Why the down vote?

Comment: Can you provide the full Message of the Exception? When i try it myself i am able to access the User directorys but get an exception at the ...\AppData\Local\Application Data Folder. This folder is protected by the OS. Is using "SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly" and going on from there an option?

Comment: I'll try skipping that particular folder and see if it works on the remainder.  I'll update within 24 hours.  Thanks Hyarus.

Answer (score 0):

You need administrator rights to do this.

The "highestAvailable" level may provide these, but only if you run the program as an administrator.
Using the "requireAdministrator" level may be the better alternativ here. The system will prompt for credentials if the process is not running with administrative permissions.

*Note: For Debugging you might need to run your IDE as an administrator*

Comment: I have the IDE running as Administrator and I have tried requireAdministratoras well.

Comment: @BillGreer Did you try requireAdministrator?